# Convert an SVG to PNG based on the path of the image

Tags: javascript, angular, svg

Is it possible to convert an SVG image to the PNG format in an angular project?

I found this library [save-svg-as-png](https://www.npmjs.com/package/save-svg-as-png), but it requires the id of an svg canvas. Whereas in my code, I am displaying the SVG image with the `img` tag:

```
<img src="path/to/mysvg/mysvg.svg">
```

Is there a way to access the inline svg that is inside the image, or another library where it is possible to provide the url of the svg image instead of the id of the canvas?

PS: I found some libraries like [svg2png](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg2png) and [convert-svg-to-png](https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-svg-to-png) that takes the path of the svg as a parameter, but they both depend on nodejs.

Comment: Can you not just give it an ID?  Is it the only image?  Is it the only SVG?

Comment: I can see it can be used like this `saveSvgAsPng(document.getElementById("diagram"), "diagram.png");` you can use id/class name whatever works for you to select the element.

Comment: I assigned an Id to the image and I tried first with the `document.getElementById("diagram")` but the method `saveSvgAsPng` did not accept it. Then I tried to work with the `nativeElement` of the `ViewChild` but I got the error `an HTMLElement or SVGElement is required`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with [angular-svg-icon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-svg-icon) saved the day.

In my HTML, I displayed my svg image this way:

```
<svg-icon #mySVGImg src="path/to/mysvg/mysvg.svg" [svgStyle]="{ 'width.px':140, 'height.px':140 }"></svg-icon>
```

and in my typescript, I called the `saveSvgAsPng` method like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as svg from 'save-svg-as-png';
// Other imports

@Component({
  //....
})
export class MyTSPage implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild("mySVGImg", { read: ElementRef }) mySVGImg: ElementRef;

    myConvertMethod() {
        svg.saveSvgAsPng(this.mySVGImg.nativeElement.querySelector("svg"), "pngtest.png");
    }
}
```

Calling `myConvertMethod` method saved a new png file with the name `pngtest.png`